# Convert String to int inside "if" statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement, integer, int

I'm working ahead in my Intro Java programming course and was wondering if there is a shortcut to what I am trying to do in an `if` statement.

Basically, my program receives a two-character abbreviation for a playing card and returns the full card name (**i.e. "QS" returns "Queen of Spades."**)

Now my question is:
When I write the `if` statements for the numbered cards 2-10, do I need a separate statement for each number or can I combine them in one `if` statement?

Check where my code says **IS AN INTEGER** (obviously not Java notation.)  Here is a fragment of my code to clarify:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the card notation: ");
        String x = in.nextLine();
        if (x.substring(0,1).equals("A")){
            System.out.print("Ace");
        }
        else if(x.substring(0,1) IS AN INTEGER) <= 10)){   // question is about this line
            System.out.print(x);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Error.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you enter "ten of spades" as "10S" or "TS"?

Comment: Should be 10S, which will throw a curveball at any attempt to convert to char

Comment: So a 10 of any suit is a _three_ character abbreviation?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this instead:

```
    char c = string.charAt(0);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        // do something
    }
```

`x.substring(0,1)` is pretty much the same as `string.charAt(0)`.  The difference is charAt returns a `char` and substring returns a `String`.

If this weren't homework, I'd recommend you use [`StringUtils.isNumeric`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNumeric%28java.lang.String%29) instead.  You'd be able to say:

```
    if (StringUtils.isNumeric(x.substring(0, 1))) {
        System.out.println("is numeric");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the first one will be sufficient.  I think I'll be able to work around the 10 if I just use a separate IF statement for that.  Thumbs-up for the quick response ^-^

Answer (score 1):

Another way to convert a string to an int is:

```
Integer number = Integer.valueOf("10");
```

Also another approach you might consider is using a class or enum.

```
public class Card {
    // Feel free to change this
    public char type; // 1 - 10, J, Q, K, A
    public char kind; // Spades, Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds

    public Card(String code) {
        type = code.charAt(0);
        kind = code.charAt(1);
    }

   public boolean isGreaterThan(Card otherCard) {
       // You might want to add a few helper functions
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the briefest solution I can think of:

```
private static Map<String, String> names = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("A", "Ace"); 
    put("K", "King"); 
    put("Q", "Queen"); 
    put("J", "Jack"); 
}};
```

then in your main:

```
String x = in.nextLine();
if (x.startsWith("10")) { // special case of two-character rank
    System.out.print("Rank is 10");
} else if (Character.isDigit(x.charAt(0)){
    System.out.print("Rank is " + x.charAt(0));
} else
    System.out.print("Rank is: " + names.get(x.substring(0,1));
}
```